# Laravel 4.2: Include a PHP file (library) into controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm doing a project using Laravel 4.2 where I need to include a PHP file (a library to transform a PDF into Text) into the controller, and then return a variable with the text, any idea how?

This is my **controller**:

```
public function transform() {
    include ('includes/vendor/autoload.php');
}
```

And my **/app/start/global.php** file:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/includes',

));
```

And this is the **error**:

```
include(includes/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're right bro, but, i find another way, maybe not the right way, but it works.

Is like this, I created a new folder called Includes and put my files in there, then in the /app/start/global.php i added this line:

```
require app_path().'/includes/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And now is working :D

Answer (score 16):

You can create a new directory somewhere in your app directory, for example, `app/libraries`

Then in your composer.json file, you can include `app/libraries` in your autoload classmap:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/libraries", <------------------ YOUR CUSTOM DIRECTORY
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
}
```

Be sure to run a `composer dump-autoload` after modifying your composer.json.

Let's assume your class name is called `CustomClass.php` and it is located in the `app/libraries` directory (so the full path is `app/libraries/CustomClass.php`). If you have properly namespaced your class, by convention, your namespace would probably be named `libraries`. Just for the sake of clarity, we will call our namespace `custom` to avoid any confusion with the directory.

```
$class = new \custom\CustomClass();
```

Alternatively, you can give it an alias in your `app/config/app.php` file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => array(
    ...
    'CustomClass'   => 'custom\CustomClass',
    ...
)
```

And you can instantiate the class from anywhere in your application as you would with any other class:

```
$class = new CustomClass();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have added `"app/libraries"` to my composer.json autoload->classmap section. I then added `TextCleaner => 'libraries\TextCleaner` to my app/config/app.php aliases. I have tried to instantiate my class like `$imageCleaner = new \libraries\TextCleaner()` AND like `$imageCleaner = new TextCleaner();` and both error out for me saying the class doesn't exist. Yes I have run the composer dump-autload successfully.

Comment: @BillGarrison Ensure that you have namespaced your class. Assume that your namespace for your class is called 'helpers' (`namespace helpers;` at the top of your class). In your config/app.php file, you would include it as `'TextCleaner' => 'helpers\TextCleaner'`. I edited the original answer to help clarify.

Comment: helped me today :) +1