# Including Woocommerce API library in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, woocommerce, composer-php

I'm trying to include this [Woocommerce API library](https://packagist.org/packages/woothemes/woocommerce-api) into my project. This is not a Laravel specific package. But, I am having trouble while including this in my project.

#### `autoload-classmap.php`

```
'WC_API_Client' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/class-wc-api-client.php',
'WC_API_Client_Authentication' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/class-wc-api-client-authentication.php',
'WC_API_Client_Exception' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/exceptions/class-wc-api-client-exception.php',
'WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/exceptions/class-wc-api-client-http-exception.php',
'WC_API_Client_HTTP_Request' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/class-wc-api-client-http-request.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/abstract-wc-api-client-resource.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Coupons' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-coupons.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Custom' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-custom.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Customers' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-customers.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Index' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-index.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Order_Notes' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-order-notes.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Order_Refunds' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-order-refunds.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Orders' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-orders.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Products' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-products.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Reports' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-reports.php',
'WC_API_Client_Resource_Webhooks' => $vendorDir . '/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-resource-webhooks.php',
```

I'd like to know, because this is NOT a Laravel package, whether I need to include this file in the controller and how I go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4.2: Include a PHP file (library) into controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695408/laravel-4-2-include-a-php-file-library-into-controller)

Answer (score 2):

```
"require": {
    "woothemes/woocommerce-api": "dev-master"
     },
"require-dev": {

},

"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "app\\": "app/"
    },
    "files":[
    "vendor/woothemes/woocommerce-api/lib/woocommerce-api.php"
    ]
},
```

So require the woocommerce api then add the main require file to the files array of composer. then you can composer dump-autoload and will have the library for use.

Answer (score 0):

I have called

```
composer require automattic/woocommerce
```

then in my PHP file:

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://example.com', 
    'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
    'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
);
```

and it worked with no problems

https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php

Comment: Automattic\WooCommerce is not maintained properly.