# Laravel check if user is banned, if so, stike his name

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to check if an user is banned, this works, but now I want to have a function that returns the username striked.

This is what I have now:

```
public static function CheckIfBanned($username)
{
    $CheckBan = Ban::orderBy('expire', 'ASC')->where('lifted', '=', '0')
                                            ->where('expire', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now())
                                            ->where('username', '=', $username)
                                            ->get();

    if ($CheckBan)
    {
        return '<s>'.$username.'</s>';
    }
    else
    {
        return $username;
    }
}
```

So, this works, but it takes only the first user.

Do I need to add an foreach? If so, where and how?

Comment: Are you trying to print a single username or multiple?

Comment: I want to display this on multiple usernames. Something like they have in MyBB. So when a user is banned, he needs to be displayed with a strike `<s>username</s>`, else he needs to be displayed the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code works fine and given a list of usernames, simply calling your function in a loop will give you your desired result:

```
$displayableUsernames = [];
foreach($usernames as $username) {
    $displayableUsernames[] = CheckIfBanned($username);
}
```

With the above code snippet, you can parse through a list of plain-text usernames and add it to an array of displayable usernames that you can use.

From what I understand, however, this is a process that needs to be done **EVERY** time you ask for a User's username from the database.

For that reason, it might be a cleaner and more elegant solution if you used an Eloquent Accessor method that gets the User's username using your function:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function getUsernameAttribute($value)
    {
        return CheckIfBanned($value);
    }
}
```

Documentation for Eloquent accessor methods can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

**EDIT:**

If your `CheckIfBanned()` function is within your `Helper` class, you can call it with something similar the following code in your `User.php` model class:

```
use App\Controllers\Helper;

class User extends Eloquent {
    public function getUsernameAttribute($value)
    {
        return Helpers::CheckIfBanned($value);
    }
}
```

Please note that I do not know what your actual namespace is for your `Helper` class, so you will have to import your `Helper` class with the proper namespace.

Using this accessor in practice, you can simply call the following code:

```
$user = User::find($id);

$username = $user->username; // This will automatically call your CheckIfBanned() function
```

Comment: So I need to add the first snippet to my function CheckIfBanned() and the second to the userClass? Or how should it be done? :p

Comment: I have the first function standing an my class `Helper` that extends `BaseController` I don't know if this can give any issues?

Comment: The second snippet is my personal preference as a  solution to your problem. Yes, add the above getUsernameAttribute() method to your User class. I gave two solutions here. The first snippet is for when you want to construct an array/list of displayable usernames to use. You are not adding the first snippet to your function CheckIfBanned(), you are utilizing the function within a loop, rather. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Okay, `Class 'Controllers\Helper' not found` is the error I get now, But the class `Helper` does exist?! Class helper does extend the BaseController, can this cause the issue?

Comment: What is the namespace of your `Helper` class? It should be at the top of your file

Comment: Oh, I don't have a namespace... I didn't know I should use that. How should I need to name it? And if I do so, will this change the use of the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91781/discussion-between-robin-r-and-eluong).

Comment: For more information on namespaces: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

For information on importing namespaced classes into Laravel via Composer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695408/laravel-4-2-include-a-php-file-library-into-controller/25695603#25695603

Comment: The issue I also have now, is that the usernames that aren't banned, the don't display... Is there also another possibility to get the role or when the user has a specified role_id (user table) tat they are only then displayed with their names striked? Because I think that would be a much effective way to 'store' the banned users.