# How to add Libraries folder in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to add libraries folder in laravel 5.0. I try to follow these steps [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695408/laravel-4-2-include-a-php-file-library-into-controller)
but I get an error.

```
Class 'Libraries\Myclass' not found
```

this is my composer.json

```
{
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"            
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/Libraries"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

see the **autoload-dev**. I add my library (app/Libraries) folder and then I run this command **composer dump-autoload**
and here's my code of my class inside Libraries/Myclass.php

```
namespace Libraries\Myclass;

class Myclass{
    public function hello(){
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

I don't know If my code is good enough. Please correct me If I get wrong. I'm trying to explore more in laravel 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in similar situation and figured it out a clean way (in my opinion). I am using Laravel 5.4. My class was named as "Ldap", here is how i did.

1. created a Libraries directory under app and added my class file:

   app/Libraries/Ldap.php (having namespace Libraries\Ldap)
2. in composer.json file,

   ```
   "autoload": {
       ...

       "classmap": [
           "database",
           "app/Libraries" <------------ Added libraries directory
       ], 

       ...
    }
   ```
3. Went to terminal and did run this command: composer dump-autoload
4. opened aap/config/app.php file and did add following code under "aliases":

   ```
   'aliases' => [
       ...

       'Ldap' => \Libraries\Ldap\Ldap::class <--- Added this line
   ],
   ```
5. now in my controller, i just instantiate my class:

   ```
   // Ldap class object
   $ldapObj = new Ldap();
   ```

It worked like a charm! 
Happy laraveling!

Answer (score 1):

```
    {
     "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"            
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Libraries"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

run `composer dump-autoload` command and use your library.

Answer (score 0):

For laravel 8, the following method works:

In `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
            "Lib\\": "lib/" <------- Add this
        }
    },
```

And then run `composer dump-autoload`